# Функция watermark и способы её применения

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Меня интересует функция watermark и способы её применения, если можно, то меня больше интересуют примеры автоматического наложения "подписи" (которая сама является не текстом, а картинкой) на изображения. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это делается?

Заранее благодарен. С уважением, Владимир.

Answer (score 1):

Такой функции (watermark) нету. Вам придется написать данную обработку самому. Очень удобна для этого библиотека GD2, которая, как правило, всегда подключена к PHP. Как именно это сделать описано, например, [здесь](http://www.softtime.ru/forum/read.php?id_forum=1&id_theme=39132&page=1), или [здесь](http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/php/watermark/).

Comment: Ды Вы что? Такая функция как раз есть в php, это и есть библиотека GD, а меня интересует, как пользоватьсья этой функцией, ну или ей подобной.
Короче, мне нужен эффект такой же, как и используется в фотобанках. Помогите, кто знает об этом.

Comment: Очень интересно, что за такая тайная функция.

Answer (score 1):

- [Adding watermarks](http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php) to images using alpha channels.
- [Добавление водяных знаков](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#watermarking) через [ImageMagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) (подключается к PHP через [imagick](http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick)).

Answer (score 1):

Готовый вариант: http://fstrange.ru/coder/php/php-watermark.html
Другие варианты: поиск по словам php, watermark.